# javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.disney.zeus.client.entity.MaterialAudioChannel#<null>]

Tags: jpa-2.0

i have a problem while deleting the child entities, this is giving me the below exception
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.myproj.test.entity.XYZ#].

parent Entity :

```
...

public class ABC implements java.io.Serializable {

...

 // it has a @oneToMany relationship with XYZ entity as specified below.

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "abbc", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<XYZ > xyzs;
```

}

...

Child Entity :-

```
 ...

 public class XYZ implements java.io.Serializable {

  ...

  // and this has @manyToOne relation as below

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="ABC_ID")
  private ABC abc;

  ...
```

}

from service calss iam invoking delete method by passing the entity instance to delete as below.

delete(XYZ xyzs){

```
 for(XYZ xyz :xyzs){

 // i have the entityManger instance and calling remove

 entityManager..find(XYZ.class, xyz.getXyzId());

 entityManger.remove(xyz);

 }
```

}

now it is giving me the above specified exception.
Plase any one help me out in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Surendar Reddy. K

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove XYZ from parent collection only. You have List of XYZ in ABC. 
So for delete:

1. get XYZ from db.
2. get restective(related to XYZ) ABC from db.
3. remove XYZ from list in ABC.
4. delete XYZ.

It will work fine